# mongoose pre save - check if username taken

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

THis is my mongoose model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username : { 
        type : String , 
        unique : true,
        required: true,
        trim : true
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        trim : true
    }
})

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var self = this;
    User.find({name : self.username}, function (err, docs) {
        if (!docs.length){
            next();
        }else{                
            console.log('user exists: ',self.username);
            next(new Error("User exists!"));
        }
    });
}) ;


var User = mongoose.model('User' , UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

My route handler for this is :

```
router.post('/login' , (req , res) => {
    var user = new User({
      username : req.body.username,
      password : req.body.password
    })
    res.send('Clear!')


})
```

This should stop the save if the username is already taken,instead it just continues and writes "Clear!".Am i better off using the validation in the router itself rather than the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the user to do the validation

```
router.post('/login' , (req , res) => {
    var user = new User({
      username : req.body.username,
      password : req.body.password
    })
    user.save(function(err){
       if(err) return res.send('Error')
       return res.send("Clear!")
    })
})
```

Comment: Works thanks! one clarification - so the else clause of the prehook :
`console.log('user exists: ',self.username);
            next(new Error("User exists!"));` is never actually used? since it prints out the error in the router

Comment: The else clause is how the error is propagated from the hook to the router. Calling `next()` will pass `null` to the first parameter of the `save` callback, while calling `next(new Error())` (or really any truthy value) will result in the callback having a value, and therefore the `if(err)` clause evaluating true.

Comment: You can put the error message on the hook inside the controller's error part
`if (err) return res.send(err.message);`

Answer (score 0):

Pre-save happens, logically, before the save action completes.

You never call `user.save()`, so there's no save action.

It's also worth noting if you use `User.create()` or `User.update()` there are additional considerations (config options) if you want to have pre-save fire.

Also, note that this is not going to solve concurrency problems; if you have two people attempt to save the same name at a timeframe pretty close to each other, they will be able to do so unless you also mark the field `unique` to enforce a unique constraint in the DB as  you did, however note also that in that case you'll get an error that you want to catch and handle appropriately (which you're not currently doing).

I'd also like to point out that you're currently *creating* a user on the Login URL.  Is that really what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out,i was just trying some node stuff.Also what are your views on "Am i better off using the validation in the router itself rather than the model"?

Comment: If you want to guarantee uniqueness, you have to do it in the DB and be ready to handle the error (err.code will equal 11000 if memory serves).  The issue with proactively checking like you are doing is that it's an extra round-trip to the DB, which can slow down the overall request (impact to the user) and also there's no guarantee that another record won't be created in the time between  your check hitting the database and the save call hitting the DB (impact to the system integrity).